# New Instagram API how to pull images from other users then mine

Tags: php, instagram

As many of you might know Instagram changed their API and now it dont really look like it's possible to pull images other then my own.

When trying to make a new submission under the following category "I want to display hashtag content and public content on my website." i get the following

**Error:**

> This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).

Have anyone found a way around this? if then please tell me!

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis Please read the question again? i can't see what more info you want. i have specified what i am trying to do and what error im' getting.

Comment: It sounds like you applied for public content permission for one specific hashtag? E.g you were building a website for an even that used a hashtag for content and you were trying to auth a client for that specific website and hashtag?? As they say, they do not see this as a valid use case for their API (personally I disagree, but it's their API at the end of the day).    

you could instead try explaining that you have build a platform which allows a website owner to select a hashtag. That it is not just usable for one hashtag and one website.

Answer (score 2):

Instagrams new policy stops getting images from hashtags.. But you can look at [this](https://github.com/Bolandish/Instagram-Hashtag-Grabber) :)

Comment: holy cow, this is gold :D